# I want to select text on div with keyboard(Just like we select text with mouse)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a requirement where I need to select bold text (or any other subtext in following parragraph) using only keyboard. Is it possible to do so?

The reading text on the

**following page is longer than usual and is used as the basis for all the questions and examples in this section**. However, in the real IELTS test the 40 or 50 questions will be based on three texts not just one, and the questions will not test your understanding of a point in the text more than once, as they may do here.

EDIT::

I have added tabindex to div and it gets the focus now, but any Idea how I can select the text using "Shift+ left/right arrow"?

Comment: See if this can help you : https://javascript.info/selection-range

Comment: It does not help, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

> First put that bold text in span and give a class and for
>
> both must be different from each other

```
 <p>The reading text on the
<span class="Selectonly" unselectable="on"><b>following page is longer than usual and is used as the basis for all the questions and examples in this section</b></span></p>
```

or

And use user-select element

```css
.Selectonly{
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: My text to be selected is not decided when we render the html, it is user activity, user can select any text that he wishes.